# How to convert a varchar column to bit column in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

`Flag1` is a `varchar` column with values "true" and "false". I need to convert this into bit column.

When I try to do this:

```
Convert(Bit,Flag1)
```

it shows an error

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Syntax error converting the varchar value 'False' to a column of data type bit.
```

Comment: Just a reminder. Could you double-check your result to prevent false positives and negatives? Please run this:

Comment: declare @flag1 varchar(25) = '     True' -- leading blanks

Comment: select case @flag1 when 'true' then 1 when 'false' then 0 else 0 end

Comment: @JianHuang please don't answer in comment, also please review the existing answers.

Comment: @DanAndrews sorry. still new in SO. Will move the answer.

Comment: @JianHuang Welcome to SO!  It is a very friendly place to be, except the users are not friendly at all. :)

Comment: @DanAndrews I have fun here. ^_^. However, I cannot delete my previous comments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suspect that there are other values in addition to 'true' and 'false' in the field 'Flag1'. So check for the values in Flag1.

select distinct Flag1 from YouTable.

Here is my proof:

```
declare @Flag varchar(25) = 'False'
select CONVERT(Bit, @Flag)
```

It works fine.

However, this will give the same error.

```
declare @Flag varchar(25) = '  False' -- Pay attention to the the space in '  False'!
select CONVERT(Bit, @Flag)
```

-> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '  False' to data type bit.

Pay attention to the the space in '  False' in the error message!

Answer (score 6):

While selecting from table, you can do this:

```
SELECT CASE Flag1 WHEN 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FlagVal
```

Syntax:

```
CASE input_expression 
     WHEN when_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END 
Searched CASE expression:
CASE
     WHEN Boolean_expression THEN result_expression [ ...n ] 
     [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```

Comment: I needed to add the "END" keyword to the example. `SELECT CASE Flag1 WHEN 'true' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS FlagVal`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it is to do with if you have other values in your column. Its to do with how you've defined "true" or "false". SQL thinks it's a string rather than a bit. In your column I'd suggest using a Case Statement like:

```
select ...., case when ColumnName = "True" then 1 else 0 end as Flag1
```

Make sure you do not have any spaces in true or false. For that you could use:

```
rtrim(ltrim(ColumnName))
```

To remove any spaces.